# Truffle contract migration issue with infura ropsten

Tags: deployment, ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle, consensys-truffle

While migrating my smart contract,I came across an issue for command below

truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten.Issue as given below

Using network 'ropsten'.
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Unknown address - unable to sign transaction for this address

But my address is having enough ether as it is displayed both in Metamask and Etherscan.
Can anybody point out why this issue is happening?

I am using ropsten infura for truffle-hd-wallet-provider.Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Anu

Comment: There have been several issues with ropsten and infura when used together. I would suggest you to use Rinkeby

Comment: @Skyuppercut Thanks for suggesting !Got it sorted out anyways.

Comment: How did u fix it @AnuSurya?

Comment: @ichimaru Error was regarding signing transaction.I did some corrections in my code for signing using private key.And also made mentioning of the gasdebitaddress in my configuration file along with the network and gaslimit.Thanks!

Comment: @AnuSurya Ahh okay thanks!